# How to count repeated values using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am trying to find the number of times the same values are repeated in particular column.

Then I need to paste the value and the count of the repeated value in column A and B of another sheet.

I need to count the number of times repeated values:

```
PSV_Cust_1
PSV_Cust_1
PSV_Cust_1
PSV_Cust_1
PSV_Cust_1
PSV_Cust_2
PSV_Cust_2
PSV_Cust_2
PSV_Cust_2
PSV_Cust_3
PSV_Cust_3
PSV_Cust_3
PSV_Cust_3
PSV_Cust_4
PSV_Cust_4
PSV_Cust_4
PSV_Cust_5
PSV_Cust_5
PSV_Cust_5
PSV_Cust_5
PSV_Cust_5
PSV_Cust_5
PSV_Cust_5
PSV_Cust_5
```

Result should be:

```
Value        Count
PSV_Cust_1   5
PSV_Cust_2   4
PSV_Cust_3   4
PSV_Cust_4   3
PSV_Cust_5   7
```

Please any one help to get the outpu using VBA code.

Comment: Use a Pivot table. You don't need vba for this :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could use pivot tables or worksheet functions like COUNTIF.

Answer (score 10):

As others have suggested, a `Pivot Table` would be the simplest way to accomplish this. Here's how:

> **1)** Select the rows you want to count
>
> **2)** Choose `Insert -> PivotTable`
>   from the ribbon
>
> **3)** A window will appear, click `Ok` to create your pivot
>   table:

[image]

> **4)** On the right under "PivotTable Field List: Choose fields to add to report:" click the checkbox next:

[image]

> **5)** Now drag the checkbox field you just clicked down to the "Values" list and let go:

[image]

> **6)** That's it! You will now have what you asked for:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Pictures make things so much easier.

Comment: thank you,i will use pvote table option , i can able to get my out now

Comment: If this or any other answer helped solve your question, please mark it as solved. It helps others know there was a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This macro will do what you need:

```
Sub Summarize(rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range)
    Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim var As Variant

    For Each rng In rngSource
        If rng <> "" Then
            If d.Exists(rng.Value) Then
                d(rng.Value) = d(rng.Value) + 1
            Else
                d.Add rng.Value, 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rng

    rngTarget = "Value"
    rngTarget.Offset(, 1) = "Count"
    Set rng = rngTarget.Offset(1)
    For Each var In d.Keys
        rng = var
        rng.Offset(, 1) = d(var)
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

You need to add a reference to the *Microsoft Scripting Library* in the Visual Basic Editor (Tools->References). You can call it like this:

```
Summarize Sheet1.Range("A1:A24"), Sheet1.Range("C1")
```

Comment: thank you,i will use pvote table option , i can able to get my out now

Answer (score 2):

The COUNTIF(range, value) function will do what you want - it has the advantage that you can more easily constrain the values you want to search for (compared to a pivot table). Imagine your data is in range "Sheet1!A1:A25" which you have named "customers" (you do this by selecting the range and typing `customers` in the address box to the left of the formula bar).and contains "customer 1, customer 2... through customer 10", and you only want to know how many times customers 1 and 5 appear, you can create the following on sheet2

```
col A        col B
Value        count
customer 1   =COUNTIF(customers, A1)
customer 5   =COUNTIF(customers, A2)
```

Of course you can just drag the formula down from cell B1 - you don't need to type it in again.

This will count the customers, update automatically, ... I think it's easier than a pivot table in this example.

Comment: I don't think it's easier than a pivot table if you want to capture a changing list of customers.

Comment: @DougGlancy - I agree with you. I am giving this as an alternative "if you only want to know the number of times certain customers appear". The other thing I don't like about pivot tables is that they can change size, and need recalculating. I thought the OP would benefit from seeing the alternatives. I am not saying this is "better", just "different" - and I think the 9 "helpful" flags that Siddarth Rout got should be enough to get OP's attention to the concept of pivot tables...