# Find duplicates in a column and add their corresponding values from another column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have column A with staff ids and hours worked in column K.

I would like if a staff id appears more than once to add hours worked and put the result in another column corresponding to the first instance of that staff id and the duplicates being 0.

This is for a monthly report and there may be over 2k records at any point.

Comment: did you try anything?? do you really need to do it with VBA as a pivot table could be good enough to solve your problem

Comment: indeed use a pivot table, problem solved I guess...

Comment: exactly, use a pivot table to group and sum your data...

Comment: The reason I want to use VBA is because this is one part of the entire process, which is in place and is in VBA. The entire report is run monthly and is calculated using VBA, and the aim is to minimise manual intervention as much as possible. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: well, if VBA is the only way, then why not query the worksheet as a table (using ADO and OLE DB Excel driver) and in your query you would do a GROUP BY to simulate the Pivot Table grouping in your dataset, then all you have to do is **Range.CopyFromRecordset** and voila !

Comment: another alternative in Excel VBA is to use the worksheet functions COUNTIF and SUMIF in your VBA code (Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf) **if you write some code, we'll help you fix it**

Comment: Thanks Philip. I will try your suggestion and keep you posted.

Comment: you might find this useful: [MSDN - Much ADO about Text Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx) as you'll be doing essentially the same thing, just treating your worksheet as a table!

Answer (score 3):

As everyone else said, a Pivot Table really is the best way. If you're unsure how to use a PivotTable or what it's good for, [refer to this SO post where I explain in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896188/how-to-count-repeated-values-using-vba/14902257#14902257).

Anyway, I put together the below VBA function to help get you started. It's by no means the most efficient approach; it also makes the following assumptions:

> - `Sheet 1` has all the data
> - `A` has Staff Id
> - `B` has Hours
> - `C` is reserved for Total Hours
> - `D` will be available for processing status output

This of course can all be changed very easily by altering the code a bit. Review the code, it's commented for you to understand.

The reason a `Status` column must exist is to avoid processing a `Staff Id` that was already processed. You could very alter the code to avoid the need for this column, but this is the way I went about things.

**CODE**

```
Public Sub HoursForEmployeeById()

    Dim currentStaffId As String
    Dim totalHours As Double

    Dim totalStaffRows As Integer
    Dim currentStaffRow As Integer
    Dim totalSearchRows As Integer
    Dim currentSearchRow As Integer

    Dim staffColumn As Integer
    Dim hoursColumn As Integer
    Dim totalHoursColumn As Integer
    Dim statusColumn As Integer

    'change these to appropriate columns
    staffColumn = 1
    hoursColumn = 2
    totalHoursColumn = 3
    statusColumn = 4

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    totalStaffRows = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, staffColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    For currentStaffRow = 2 To totalStaffRows
        currentStaffId = Cells(currentStaffRow, staffColumn).Value

        'if the current staff Id was not already processed (duplicate record)
        If Not StrComp("Duplicate", Cells(currentStaffRow, statusColumn).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            'get this rows total hours
            totalHours = CDbl(Cells(currentStaffRow, hoursColumn).Value)
            'search all subsequent rows for duplicates
            totalSearchRows = totalStaffRows - currentStaffRow + 1
            For currentSearchRow = currentStaffRow + 1 To totalSearchRows
                If StrComp(currentStaffId, Cells(currentSearchRow, staffColumn), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    'duplicate found: log the hours worked, set them to 0, then mark as Duplicate
                    totalHours = totalHours + CDbl(Cells(currentSearchRow, hoursColumn).Value)
                    Cells(currentSearchRow, hoursColumn).Value = 0
                    Cells(currentSearchRow, statusColumn).Value = "Duplicate"
                End If
            Next
            'output total hours worked and mark as Processed
            Cells(currentStaffRow, totalHoursColumn).Value = totalHours
            Cells(currentStaffRow, statusColumn).Value = "Processed"
            totalHours = 0  'reset total hours worked
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: ah...crap. Looks like a good exercise then for the OP ;) This is untested and as-is, it should serve as a good enough starting point though. Thanks for catching that. I unfortunately don't have time to debug right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the data table located in range A1:B10 with headers and results written to column C.

```
Sub Solution()

Range("c2:c10").Clear

Dim i
For i = 2 To 10

    If WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:a10"), Cells(i, 1), Range("C1:C10")) = 0 Then

        Cells(i, "c") = WorksheetFunction.SumIf( _
                         Range("A1:a10"), Cells(i, 1), Range("B1:B10"))
    Else
        Cells(i, "c") = 0
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Kaz Jaw & @Sam, thank you for the suggestions and help. I have tweaked your codes slightly, as required, and it seems to be giving the desired result. Your inputs have been very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()

    Dim lastRow As Integer, num As Integer, i As Integer
    lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 2 To lastRow
        num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)

        If i = num Then
            Cells(i, 3) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A" & lastRow), Cells(i, 1), Range("B1:B" & lastRow))
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

BEFORE

[image]

AFTER

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below code identifies duplicate value in a column and highlight with red. Hope this might be of some help.

```
  iLastRow = Cells(chosenExcelSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Determine the last row to look at     
    Set rangeLocation = Range("A1:A" & iLastRow)

    'Checking if duplicate values exists in same column
        For Each myCell In rangeLocation
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rangeLocation, myCell.Value) > 1 Then
                myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3'Highlight with red Color
            Else
                myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2'Retain white Color
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub SelectColoredCells()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColor As Long
    Dim rColored As Range

    'Select the color by name (8 possible)
    'vbBlack, vbBlue, vbGreen, vbCyan,
    'vbRed, vbMagenta, vbYellow, vbWhite
    lColor = RGB(156, 0, 6)

    'If you prefer, you can use the RGB function
    'to specify a color
    'Default was lColor = vbBlue
    'lColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)

    Set rColored = Nothing
    For Each rCell In Selection
        If rCell.Interior.Color = lColor Then
            If rColored Is Nothing Then
                Set rColored = rCell
            Else
                Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If rColored Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells match the color"
    Else
        rColored.Select
        MsgBox "Selected cells match the color:" & _
            vbCrLf & rColored.Address
    End If
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rColored = Nothing
End Sub
```

this highlights the duplicates