# How many times does each value appear in a column?

Tags: excel

I have a column with time data like this:

```
17:27:31
17:27:32
17:27:32
17:27:33
17:27:33
17:27:34
17:27:34
17:27:34
17:27:35
17:27:36
```

I want to count how many times each value repeats:

```
Value      Count
17:27:31   1
17:27:32   2
17:27:33   2
17:27:34   3
17:27:35   1
17:27:36   1
```

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: Use `countif()` function

Comment: Similar to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414739/excel-vba-code-to-find-duplicates-in-a-column-and-add-their-corresponding-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second Dave's idea. I'm not always fond of pivot tables, but in this case they are pretty straightforward to use.

Here are my results:

[image]

It was so simple to create it that I have even recorded a macro in case you need to do this with [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications):

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("Table1[[#All],[DATA]]").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table1", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
        :="Sheet3!R3C7", TableName:="PivotTable4", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Cells(3, 7).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("DATA")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable4").PivotFields("DATA"), "Count of DATA", xlCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use [**`CountIf`**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx).  Put the following code in B1 and drag down the whole column

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The quickest way would be with a pivot table. Make sure your column of data has a header row, highlight the data and the header, from the insert ribbon select pivot table and then drag your header from the pivot table fields list to the row labels and to the values boxes.