# How to count the number of different items in a range without use a pivot table excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large range with various repeating id's.  I want to know how many unique id's are in the range, but I don't want to use a pivot table.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661016/how-many-times-do-each-value-appear-in-a-column)  is related, but does not have the answer.  Is there a simple way to do this using VBA?

I also saw [this](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip061.htm), but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simplest way I've found:

```
Function Count_Uniques(cell_range As Range)
    Dim n As Long
    Dim cells1 As Range
    Dim unique_count As Collection
    Set unique_count = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
        For Each cells1 In cell_range
                 unique_count.Add cells1.Value, CStr(cells1.Value)
        Next cells1
    On Error GoTo 0

    Count_Uniques = unique_count.Count

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

May you want to filter the column without duplicates. After that, you can use a subtotal-function.

`Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
 Range("B2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,C[-1])"`

This VBA filters a list in column A, select cell B2 and write the subtotal-function in it. I got the function with "macro record".

Did it help?

https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Comment: Thanks but I can't filter the data.  This all has to be done in VBA.

Comment: `Range("A1:A6").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True` is the command for "unique filtering".

Comment: it looks interesting.  does the data change in the actual cells?  I need the data to stay in place as it's used elsewhere in the sheet.

Comment: Yes it will. Is just a hiding of specific rows so you need subtotal instead of sum function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary` object to load unique values, such as below:

```
Sub CountUnique()
    Dim oDictionary As Object
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim nCounter As Integer

    Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1:A10") 'Change the range to suit
    nCounter = 0

    For Each cel In rngData
        If Not oDictionary.exists(cel.Value) Then
            oDictionary.Add cel.Value, 0
            nCounter = nCounter + 1
        End If
    Next cel

    MsgBox nCounter


End Sub
```

Comment: I think he asking for a kind of Histogram where it's possible to know how many times a certain value appears in dataset. Isn't difficult to change this code to do that. Instead of put 0 on each Dictionary entry, check if the entry already exists and if is the case, sum + 1 for the particular entry. After that, loop through the Dictionary and show the values in other sheet.

Comment: @cantoni Thanks, but I don't want how many times each value is shown.  I want to know the total number of unique values.  So if the range had `foo, bar, bar, baz` the answer would be three.

Comment: @dwstein Did the code I offered work? If not, can I help to modify it, making it work?