# Google Sheets: Script to find duplicates in a column and add their corresponding values from another column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to accomplish a lot with little knowledge, but I have a spreedsheet with data that i want to convert into something readable that I can then display on my website.

Anyways, in column A I have a list of dates, column B a list of names, and column c a list of contributions. What I would like to do is first total the amount of contributions in C, for a date range in A.

I would then like to find all the duplicates in Column B(repeat donors), and total their contributions in C.

There is a VBA, that I found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414739/excel-vba-code-to-find-duplicates-in-a-column-and-add-their-corresponding-values) that would accomplish the second task, but ... I'm using Google Sheets. What I've been doing is sorting the sheet and totalling everything manually.

Comment: 1. Google script is **not** VBA. 2. Both Excel and Google-sheets have functions called SUMIF and SUMIFS.

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to do is first total the amount of contributions in
>   C, for a date range in A.

Use [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en&authuser=1)

---

> I would then like to find all the duplicates in Column B(repeat
>   donors), and total their contributions in C.

Assuming you have 100 records, starting from 1st row for below code.

1. In cell D1, put [`=UNIQUE(B1:B10)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en&authuser=1), it will fill D column with unique values of given range (B1:B100).
2. In cell E1, put `=SUMIF(B$1:B$100,D1,C$1:C$100)`
3. Repeat same formula in E column

Comment: Shouldn't `B$1:C$100` be `B$1:B$100` ?

Comment: Yes. `B$1:C$100` works but `B$1:B$100` is better and clearer.