# VBA duplicate issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am really stucked and I do not know how to make it possible regarding coding in VBA or any coding language. I have to do something for my workplace. I have list in the Column A in my excel sheet. I have different values in it but sometimes I have the same value in different cells in the same column. I cannot remove the duplicates because those same values are a contract-id. In the 9th column I have the total sum of the value of the contract. So it is about automatization of invoices with the help of vba.

I need to add the same values together with the total sum into a different sheet.

Let's say it looks that:

```
omni345              54€
omni334              2€
omni345              23€
```

I need to put the omni345's into one single invoice pdf. I do not know how to put them together. Furthermore I need to place those 2 same values in the invoice like this which is in a different sheet:

```
omni345     54€
omni345     23€
```

So that the client clearly can see that there are x different contracts.

What I need is the right direction how to start it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself - you are more likely to get help here if you have. I imagine a search will elicit many examples of separating data according to a value in a column and then producing a PDF.

Comment: Why use VBA. The `SUMIF` worksheet function is all you need!

Comment: yeah I do not know if I can use the sumif function together with the vba. I am quite confused. i have been trying for 4 days now and i am all new to excel and vba so yeah quite the novic-.- I am nearly finished with coding but this a major part which is missing. Well the thing is I think it is for automatization so maybe the sumif function is not the best idea.

Comment: Actually scrap that. Just use a pivot table. Google it. You don't need VBA.

Comment: nahhh i need to do invoices so pivot table is not an option i think

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414739/excel-vba-code-to-find-duplicates-in-a-column-and-add-their-corresponding-values

Comment: this is sth i am looking for but i need to put it to another sheet which is going to be the pdf file for the invoice

Comment: and also with the sumif function i need to tell every single criteria right? i just want that it takes the same id's puts them into another sheet and sums me the total of them

Comment: Record a macro of yourself doing a filter on column A, then copy/paste the results to a new sheet and end recording the macro.  That will give you a place to start.  Google "Excel VBA Loop" to turn your recorded code into a loop through the unique values in column A.  Come back when you have something and are stuck.

Comment: Thx never tried it b4 but now i do not know what function to use to get the same ids with all the necessary columns. I need to compare the same values but the same values have again different ids in another column like in "B" or in "C" so I really need to put those information in another sheet. Does sb get what i want to say? :/ It is not like copy paste will help me out here haha

Comment: Sumif is not the correct function to use here neither is vlookup i think

Comment: Start here: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Comment: solved i forgot the i = i +1 statement -.- so stupi dsorry guys